# How to improve app launching time in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, launch

My app is very slow in launch. It shows launch image for a long time. (approx. 25 seconds)

Getting this logs in my `Xcode` debugger area as below:

```
    Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 2911, TID: 1614792, Thread name: ComScore-Analytics, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication keyWindow]
PID: 2911, TID: 1614792, Thread name: ComScore-Analytics, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:

=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIWindow rootViewController]
PID: 2911, TID: 1614792, Thread name: ComScore-Analytics, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:

=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]
PID: 2911, TID: 1614792, Thread name: ComScore-Analytics, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:

=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView bounds]
PID: 2911, TID: 1614792, Thread name: ComScore-Analytics, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
```

(Xcode 9, app support for iOS 9,10,11, Objective-C)

My code in AppDelegate.m is looks like this, (in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`)

```
self.shareWindow = [[DFWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.shareWindow.backgroundColor         = [UIColor clearColor];
    MySharingNavController *navController = [[MySharingNavController alloc] init];
    self.shareWindow.rootViewController      = navController;
    self.shareWindow.windowLevel             = 1.0f;

    // Video Window
    self.videoWindow = [[DFWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.videoWindow.backgroundColor            = [UIColor clearColor];
    MyVideoNavControllerViewController* videoRootViewController   = [[MyVideoNavControllerViewController alloc] init];
    self.videoWindow.rootViewController         = videoRootViewController;
    self.videoWindow.windowLevel                = 2.0f;

    [[DFAxisVideoPlaybackMediator sharedVideoPlaybackMediator] setRootViewController:videoRootViewController];

    self.rootViewController = [[MyRootViewController alloc] init];

    // Main Window
    self.window = [[MyWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
```

Comment: Use Instruments to profile your app. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/LaunchingInstruments.html

Comment: The logs are saying you are creating UI on a background thread which is not allowed in iOS. You should probably checkout why that is happening. Probably is throwing the system through a loop.

Comment: Looking at the logs,  think you should open the AppDelegate.swift, in the  `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions` method, see if you set the rootViewController in a dispatch block. That block could be running on a background queue.

Comment: Since he is using `objective-c`, that would be `AppDelegate.m`

Comment: I'm setting/modifying root view controller in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but it's not in any queue or block. Should I put it in main queue? I'm setting multiple controller in AppDelegate.m  
Let me post my code for root view controller, I'm updating my question with code I've wrote in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions `